# HTTPS POST Request VBA

Tags: vba, http, outlook

I want to create `POST` request for my ServiceNow Instance API. But I don't know how to use library [VBA-Web](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web).
I want to create a row in my table in ServiceNow.
My code:

```
Sub ToRequestSN()

Dim Body As New Dictionary
Body.Add "u_any_string", "test"
Body.Add "u_any_numeral", 12

Dim Client As New WebClient
Dim Response As WebResponse
Set Response = Client.PostJson("https://instance.sn.ru/api/now/table/u_table_test", Body)

Debug.Print Response.Content

End Sub
```

But I got this message -

```
{"error":{"message":"User Not Authenticated","detail":"Required to provide Auth information"},"status":"failure"}
```

How I can log in using [VBA-Web](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web)?

Comment: So according to error it looks like VBA code is ok, but Your API requires some kind of authentication like user and password. From documentation I can see that You need to add: "--user 'username':'password'".

Comment: The way you login depends on the mechanism implemented in your API for that purpose, we can only make assumptions here. You have to read the manual.

Comment: @Mikisz Hi! Where I must to add "--user 'username':'password? Help me plz :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. I did send selected mail (email of sender) and pass to Service Now.

```
Sub RequestToSN()

Dim Client As New WebClient
Dim Response As WebResponse
Dim Auth As New HttpBasicAuthenticator
Dim Body As New Dictionary
Dim myOlSel As Outlook.Selection
Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim myOlExp As Outlook.Explorer


MsgTxt = ""
 Set myOlExp = Application.ActiveExplorer
 Set myOlSel = myOlExp.Selection
For x = 1 To myOlSel.Count
 If myOlSel.Item(x).Class = OlObjectClass.olMail Then

 Set oMail = myOlSel.Item(x)
 MsgTxt = MsgTxt & oMail.SenderName
 ''Date = Date & oMail.CreationTime
 End If
 Next x


Body.Add "u_any_string", MsgTxt
Body.Add "u_any_numeral", 123

Auth.Setup _
    Username:="user", _
    Password:="user"

Set Client.Authenticator = Auth

Set Response = Client.PostJson("https://service.sn.com/api/now/table/u_table_test", Body)

End Sub
```